# Is there a way to generate a database script for all the tables and data inside our local sql express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

We have an SQL express which comes with our Visual Studio Community 2019. Now i want to generate a full database script for our tables which include:-

1)  The data.

2)  The tables schema.

But i can not find such an option, the only option i got is to generate a schema-only script for single tables as follow:-

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Object Explorer | Select your DB | Open conext menu | Select Tasks | Generate Scripts.
2. Choose options in Advanced
   [image]

Comment: i know these steps work well with sql server but not with sql express which comes with visual studio?

Comment: To create definitions of SQL objects you can press F7 in SSMS and then select multiple objects, then press **Script Table as | CREATE TO | File**. For the data - can you try to use **Import and Export Tool**?

Comment: those tools are not available inside sql express which get shipped with VS

Comment: I can't understand, why you don't want to install SSMS?